# Cant Get Data To Return To My Grid View Using Linq in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, database, linq

Not sure why but i cant get my data to return. It starts out saying there is not data records to display. But when i select the month and year of the information i am looking for the grid view disappears. Any suggestions

```
    NutritionEntities context;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        context = new NutritionEntities();
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {            

            for (int i = DateTime.Now.Year; i > 1988; i--)
            {   
                ddlYear.Items.Add(new ListItem(i.ToString(), i.ToString()));

            }

            int selectedMonth = int.Parse(ddlMonth.SelectedValue);
            int selectedYear = int.Parse(ddlYear.SelectedValue);
            GridView1.DataSource =
                from exercise in context.Exercises
                where exercise.exerciseDate.Value.Month == selectedMonth && exercise.exerciseDate.Value.Year == selectedYear
                select new
                {
                    exercise.exerciseDate,
                    exercise.duration,
                    exercise.caloriesBurned,
                    exercise.averageHR,
                    exercise.distanceInMiles,
                    exercise.notes

                };


            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }

    protected void ddlMonth_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int selectedMonth = int.Parse(ddlMonth.SelectedValue);
        int selectedYear = int.Parse(ddlYear.SelectedValue);
        GridView1.DataSource =
            from exercise in context.Exercises
             where exercise.exerciseDate.Value.Month == selectedMonth && exercise.exerciseDate.Value.Year == selectedYear
             select new
             {
                 exercise.exerciseDate,
                 exercise.duration,
                 exercise.caloriesBurned,
                 exercise.averageHR,
                 exercise.distanceInMiles,
                 exercise.notes

             };


        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    protected void ddlYear_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int selectedMonth = int.Parse(ddlMonth.SelectedValue);
        int selectedYear = int.Parse(ddlYear.SelectedValue);
        GridView1.DataSource =
            from exercise in context.Exercises
             where exercise.exerciseDate.Value.Month == selectedMonth && exercise.exerciseDate.Value.Year == selectedYear
             select new
             {
                 exercise.exerciseDate,
                 exercise.duration,
                 exercise.caloriesBurned,
                 exercise.averageHR,
                 exercise.distanceInMiles,
                 exercise.notes

             };


        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: "It starts out saying there is not data records to display" who said this ? the GridView's EmptyDataTemplate ?

Comment: The default text in Visual basic says in the grid view "there is n data records to display". But when i select the month and year from the drop down boxes i have the gridview just disappears

Answer (score 0):

you have verify the binding of your control grid, i suggest add only object to the datasource of the grid on the pageLoad when the postback its false like this:

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

```
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
       GridView1.DataSource =
        from exercise in context.Exercises
         where exercise.exerciseDate.Value.Month == selectedMonth && exercise.exerciseDate.Value.Year == selectedYear
         select new
         {
             exercise.exerciseDate,
             exercise.duration,
             exercise.caloriesBurned,
             exercise.averageHR,
             exercise.distanceInMiles,
             exercise.notes

         };
    }
    GridView1.DataBind();
```

}

the problem is when you add the objects to datasource , when any event refresh the web page like select the control is unbinding, i hope help you,, see you!!

Comment: im not sure i get the unbinding part..can you explain a little more in detail

Comment: in your code when you valid if postback is false, in this part you add the retrieve of entity to the datasource and binding, the correct is add the objects to datasource when the postback is false and binding the grid out of valid postback like this:  if(!postback){  grid.DataSource=objectOfRetrieve;   } here !! put databinding out this valid  GridView1.DataBind();, proib !